# Python - is there a threadsafe queue that can be pickled or otherwise serialized to disk?

Tags: python, multithreading, serialization, queue, pickle

I'm after a threadsafe queue that can be pickled or serialized to disk.  Are there any datastructures in python that do this.  The standard python Queue could not be pickled.

Comment: Why not get everything from the queue and then put that into a list then pickle that list?

Comment: Pretty good suggestion, I suppose there's just the overhead of the copying.  Was hoping to serialize the queue as is.

Comment: What version of Python are you using?

Comment: Using Python 2.7.8, not 3.x.

Answer (score 3):

This can be done using the [`copy_reg`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy_reg.html) module, but it's not the most elegant thing in the world:

```
import copy_reg
import threading
import pickle
from Queue import Queue as _Queue

# Make Queue a new-style class, so it can be used with copy_reg
class Queue(_Queue, object):
    pass

def pickle_queue(q):
    # Shallow copy of __dict__ (the underlying deque isn't actually copied, so this is fast)
    q_dct = q.__dict__.copy()
    # Remove all non-picklable synchronization primitives
    del q_dct['mutex']
    del q_dct['not_empty']
    del q_dct['not_full']
    del q_dct['all_tasks_done']
    return Queue, (), q_dct

def unpickle_queue(state):
    # Recreate our queue.
    q = state[0]()
    q.mutex = threading.Lock()
    q.not_empty = threading.Condition(q.mutex)
    q.not_full = threading.Condition(q.mutex)
    q.all_tasks_done = threading.Condition(q.mutex)
    q.__dict__ = state[2]
    return q

copy_reg.pickle(Queue, pickle_queue, unpickle_queue)

q = Queue()
q.put("hey")
d = pickle.dumps(q)

new_q = pickle.loads(d)
print new_q.get()
# Outputs 'hey'
```

`copy_reg` allows you to register helper functions or pickling and unpickling arbitrary objects. So, we register a new-style version of the `Queue` class, and use the helper functions to remove all the unpickleable `Lock`/`Condition` instance variables prior to pickling, and add them back after unpickling.

Comment: Nice, I'll try it out tomorrow AM.  Thanks for responding.

Answer (score 1):

There are modules like `dill` and `cloudpickle` that already know how to serialize a `Queue`.
They already have done the `copy_reg` for you.

```
>>> from Queue import Queue
>>> q = Queue()
>>> q.put('hey')
>>> import dill as pickle
>>> d = pickle.dumps(q)
>>> _q = pickle.loads(d)
>>> print _q.get()
hey
>>>
```

It's that easy!  Just `import dill as pickle` and problem solved.

Get `dill` here: https://github.com/uqfoundation